# VBA Bloomberg API and Fields

Tags: vba, api, excel, bloomberg

I am using VBA with Bloomberg's API, and I am trying to retrieve some bulk information. I need to add a couple of "override" fields to it, and the usual procedure in the manual doesn't work.

For example:

```
Set bOverrides = bRequest.GetElement("overrides")
Set bOverridesField = bOverrides.AppendElment()
bOverridesField.SetElement "DZ379", "DETAILED"
```

gives me the error "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument".

Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the field you want to override and the value you want to override it with as two separate elements.

```
Set bOverrides = bRequest.GetElement("overrides")
Set bOverridesField = bOverrides.AppendElment()    
bOverridesField.SetElement "fieldId", "DZ379"
bOverridesField.SetElement "value", "DETAILED"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this for an array of overrides

```
OverrideFields = Array("DZ379", "DZ000")
OverrideValues = Array("DETAILED", "NEXTOVERRIDE")
Set bOverrides = req.GetElement("overrides")
For y = 0 To UBound(OverrideFields)
  Set bOverridesField = bOverrides.AppendElment()
  bOverridesField.SetElement "fieldId", OverrideFields(y)
  bOverridesField.SetElement "value", OverrideValues(y)
Next y
```